# IE / Firefox - $(window).on('popstate', function() {}

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, pushstate, history.js, popstate

i have a problem with the HTML5 History / history.js

I use the **History.pushState** to replace the Link in the address-bar.
Code:

```
function setLink() {
var
$this = $(this),
url = $this.attr('data-location'),
title = $this.attr('title')||null;
History.pushState(null,title,url);
}
```

This works perfect in all Browsers. I reloaded the site, i use the **$(window).on('popstate', function() {}** to check if a pushState is in the history.
Code:

```
$(window).on('popstate', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var
State = History.getState(),
url = State.url,
relativeUrl = url.replace(rootUrl,'');
id = url.split("/")[4];
alert(url);
alert(id);  
alert("popstate-neu-1");
if (window.history.state !== null) {    
$this = $('#' + id);
setPortfolioIsotopeOpenArgs();
} else {
alert("nothing here");
}
});
```

This works perfect in Safari (Mac/Win and iOS) but in Firefox and IE it doesn't works.
Have anyone an idea?

Thanks and sorry for my bad english.
Greets from Austria

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Anyone an idea for a solution?